# Show Google Game Services support in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I have released a game that uses Google Game Services on Google Play. Everything works, but when I look on my game in Google Play it doesn't show that it's using Game Services. Some other games do (like Riptide GP for instance). What is controlling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing the Google Play Game Services features is not sufficient, your users have to use the service for you to get the badges.

Let me quote from this video from Google I/O 2013: Practical Android Games Development
http://youtu.be/ZbQWf7C5ymU?t=23m39s

"As you get more users you will get badges. [...] However, they are not just given out because you put them in the config, and we don't snoop your APK to see if you are making API calls from there. We verify how much the feature is being used and if you meet certain threshold we give you a badge. So you need to actually integrate it, it is not a token thing that you can put there to get more eyeballs in the store."

Comment: Aha, that probably means that I never will get those badges ;-).  Either way thanks for the information; I don’t find anything about this on Google’s documentation.