# Application marked as using Play Games

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I'd like to know how to tell the Play Store that my application uses the Play Games APIs for leaderboard, achievement and soon multiplayer games.

I've seen an app where it is visible in the description of the app, as seen in that screenshot :

[image]

How can I do the same thing ? Do I have to add something in the manifest ? Change something on the developer console (I haven't seen anything related to that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting my answer from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17633229/226508

> Implementing the Google Play Game Services features is not sufficient,
>   your users have to use the service for you to get the badges.
>
> Let me quote from this video from Google I/O 2013: Practical Android
>   Games Development http://youtu.be/ZbQWf7C5ymU?t=23m39s
>
> "As you get more users you will get badges. [...] However, they are
>   not just given out because you put them in the config, and we don't
>   snoop your APK to see if you are making API calls from there. We
>   verify how much the feature is being used and if you meet certain
>   threshold we give you a badge. So you need to actually integrate it,
>   it is not a token thing that you can put there to get more eyeballs in
>   the store."